# Accepting/rejecting a feature request should lock votes on meta questions and answers

Tags: feature-request, locked-questions

A little niggle, but once a feature has been accepted or rejected it makes no difference in the long term how someone votes either on the question or on an answer.  I will grant you that there is a period of volatility after the initial imposition of the accept/reject status where some discussion and voting is valuable, but *once the status is stable* I think the question/answers should be locked.

Getting a down vote on a feature request that has already been declined, in particular, seems like adding insult to injury.

Configuring meta to derive rep from the main site instead of maintaining it's own rep a la the new StackExchange sites would mitigate this, but honestly once the issue has been decided and come to rest, what's the point of continuing to vote.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes feature-requests aren't implemented exactly, so you may want to vote them up, so that more attention is drawn to them in the future.

Also, I vote up old feature-requests to reward the ones that I think were good.  Good feature-requests that make our life easier should be able to keep earning rewards.

Comment: Voting on meta for feature requests is more of a "agree/disagree" than a rep-gathering tool.  Disagreeing (or agreeing) with a request after it's been declined already serves no purpose.

Comment: @tvan, one day the Team may reconsider an issue and go looking at old status-declined feature-requests related to it, or as has happened before, they may realized they tagged it wrong and remove the tag.

Answer (score 0):

I follow the https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/status-completed+-retag-request feed to keep up with what new questions get tagged [status-completed]. When I see something useful has been implemented that I missed, I often upvote it as a way to "tip" the person who thought of it.

However, I do find it odd that I continue to get upvotes for some feature requests I made which were implemented over a year ago.

Comment: This is why I suggested a waiting period -- say 30 days -- before closing off votes.